# Is Flyway Tool Supports extensions like .rdf,.rtf,.xml,.pks,.pkb in Oracle E-Business Suite -- > Financial Management

Tags: flyway, oracle-ebs

We planing to use Flyway for below extensions for easy deployment in Oracle E-Business Suite -- > Financial Management.

Is flyway supporting?

**Reports**

1. .rdf
2. .rdf and .rtf
3. .xml and .rtf

**Plsql Packages**

1. .pks
2. .pkb
3. .sql

Comment: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL packages are fully supported. See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate#sqlMigrationSuffixes and https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/oracle#sql-script-syntax

For reports, you will need to write your own migration resolver and executor or use Java-based migrations.